# Using Two "IsNot Nothing" in single If statement

Tags: vb.net

Need:
I need to check if either of the condition is true inside IF condition. I want to check if DrainLeftFound or DrainRightFound not empty. The condition should fail if both of the condition is not met but should exist if either on of them is true. I need to calculate the Total FoundationLength if either of the condition is true but in case of individual condition is true add up FoundationArea in total. I tried using IsNot Nothing but following problem existed.
- When first condition is empty but second condition is not empty, it
   works fine.
 - When both condition is not empty it works.
 - But it works till both condition not empty and stops working when first is empty and second is not empty.

```
    Dim FoundationLength As Double, FoundationArea As Double
    For Each Area As DrainArea In Mydrainareacalc.MyDrainarea.Values
        'If (Area.DrainLeftFound IsNot Nothing) Or (Area.DrainRightFound IsNot Nothing) Then
        If ((Area.DrainRightFound IsNot Nothing) OrElse (Area.DrainRightFound IsNot Nothing)) Then
            FoundationLength += Area.Length
            If Area.DrainLeftFound IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each LeftFound As FoundLayerDetail In Area.DrainLeftFound
                    FoundationArea += LeftFound.LayerArea
                Next
            End If
            If Area.DrainRightFound IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each RightFound As FoundLayerDetail In Area.DrainRightFound
                    FoundationArea += RightFound.LayerArea
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

**Edited**
I want to check if either one of the condition exist then execute the loop.
The code fails to the third point in above condition in this particular if condition

```
If ((Area.DrainRightFound IsNot Nothing) OrElse (Area.DrainRightFound IsNot Nothing)) Then
```

Comment: First of all, saying that something works or doesn't work is pointless. The code does what it does. If we read the code then we will see that it does what it does and therefore works. If the result of that code is not what you want it to be then you would need to tell us what you expect it to be in order for us to work out why what the code does is not what you want. Regardless of any of that, you need to debug your own code before you post here. Set a breakpoint at the top of the code and step through it line by line. You can then detect EXACTLY where the behaviour is not what you want.

Comment: I used the break point and did the step by step debugging. It failed when "But it works till both condition not empty and stops working when first is empty and second is not empty."

Comment: Could you please explain what kind of condition you need? Because right now you're checking if _**either**_ left _**or**_ right (or both) is null. Your code won't execute if both are _not_ null. Is this what you want?

Comment: because both are checking `DrainRightFound` instead of `If Area.DrainLeftFound IsNot Nothing OrElse Area.DrainRightFound IsNot Nothing Then`. The line above it that is commented out is correct.

Comment: 1) Start your question by "I'm expecting X to happen but instead, I get Y". 2) Don't talk "empty", talk `null` or `Nothing` if that's what you're referring to. 3) Don't talk "conditions", talk "variables". 4) After rewording your question, start reading it from the beginning as someone who doesn't know anything about the problem, and make sure you fully understand.

Comment: I have edited the question hope this will clarify what I exactly need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, I removed the first loop with OrElse condition, defined the length variable for individual line so that I can add up later to find total length.
**Remove:**

```
If ((Area.DrainRightFound IsNot Nothing) OrElse (Area.DrainRightFound IsNot Nothing)) Then
```

Follow the following.

```
Dim FoundationLength As Double, FoundationArea As Double, **IndividualLength As Double**
                            For Each Area As DrainArea In Mydrainareacalc.MyDrainarea.Values
                                **IndividualLength = 0**
                                If Area.DrainLeftFound IsNot Nothing Then
                                    IndividualLength = Area.Length
                                    For Each LeftFound As FoundLayerDetail In Area.DrainLeftFound
                                        FoundationArea += LeftFound.LayerArea
                                    Next
                                End If
                                If Area.DrainRightFound IsNot Nothing Then
                                    IndividualLength = Area.Length
                                    For Each RightFound As FoundLayerDetail In Area.DrainRightFound
                                        FoundationArea += RightFound.LayerArea
                                    Next
                                End If
                                **FoundationLength += IndividualLength**

                            Next
```

Answer (score 0):

What data type is DrainLeftFound and DrainRightFound? From the name it sounds like a boolean. The object Area can be nothing but the properties DrainLeftFound and DrainRightFound will have a value even if one has not been assigned. (value types)

```
Public Class AutomaticInitialization
    Private Sub AutomaticInitialization_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim da As New DrainArea
        Debug.Print(da.DrainLeftFound.ToString)
        Debug.Print(da.DrainRightFound.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class DrainArea
    Public DrainLeftFound As Boolean
    Public DrainRightFound As Boolean
End Class
```